# mentor graphics pads alternative

Tags: migration, compatibility, alternatives

Windows only SW: [mentor graphics pads](https://www.mentor.com/pcb/pads)

I want to move from Windows to linux, but I need this kind of SW for my work.

I know some alternatives with similar functionality exist, for example [KiCad](http://kicad-pcb.org/), but I need to open files created in PADS, and I been unable to open them in KiCad.

Creating them again is out of question, I have too many files.

Few simple files created in PADS: [Example files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByovI0gqb-u6dy15WVl3dkg4SFk?usp=sharing)

Is there an alternative for linux system that can open their files?